# How to access other person's mailbox ( for eg. Group mailbox) using Interop.Domino

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

We are successfully able to download an attachment from the particular mail in Lotus Notes using Interop.Domino for the logged in user.

But we are trying to access other person's mailbox( eg. group mailbox) from the user who is logged in. User has access to other person's mailbox.

In above case, we have MailServer and MailFile name but not sure how to use it without having the ID file.

Any pointers would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the user ID if the current user ID has access to the other mailboxes. You can check this in Notes Client in the database's Access Control List.
You get connected with a (mail-)database with

```
NotesSession.GetDatabase( "MailServer", "MailFile.nsf", false )
```

In general: with the Notes user ID you log in you get access to all databases and servers in Notes/Domino with the permissions set for this ID in Domino Directory or database's Access Control Lists.

Comment: There is one exception to take note of... Reading encrypted messages does require the ID file. Although encryption is used rarely in most organizations, there are some in which it is more common.  Furthermore, there is an option to "Encrypt incoming mail" in the Person document in the Domino Directory, which will encrypt all messages at delivery time, even if the sender did not explicitly request it.

Comment: Thanks Knut for the response. There seems be no issues accessing Group mailbox this way. But while accessing it from a machine where Lotus Notes is not installed and where only iNotes is available, I can not find separate MailServer and MailFile for iNotes client.